# Not able to perform Post

Tags: node.js, http, flutter, post

I want to perform post from client to server.
On the client side I'm using flutter and on the server side using nodejs. The problem is that I'm not able to perform post action. But if hardcode the route with the parameter value, I'm able to send data to server.

> static String urlLogin = API.url +
> '/authentication/api/login/ADMIN/12345';

but when I'm using below code and used body properties,not able to send data to server.

> static String urlLogin = API.url +
> '/authentication/api/login/';

my guest is there a problem with the parameter..maybe...I don't know what mistake that i have make.Hope can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

**ERROR**

```
 <pre>Cannot POST /authentication/api/login</pre>
</body>
</html>
 FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
```

**(CLIENT SITE)**

LoginPageForm.dart

```
class LoginPageForm extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPageForm({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageFormState createState() => _LoginPageFormState();
}

class _LoginPageFormState extends State<LoginPageForm> {
  TextEditingController _idController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: TextFormField(
              cursorColor: Colors.white,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              controller: _idController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "No ID",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return "Sila masukkan no id pengguna";
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: TextFormField(
              cursorColor: Colors.white,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              controller: _passwordController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Kata Laluan",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return "Sila masukkan kata laluan..";
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                var login = new LoginPost(
                    userNo: _idController.text,
                    password: _passwordController.text);
                

               //perform post
                LoginRepository.login(login.toMap()).then((response) {
                  print(response);
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              label: Text("Daftar Masuk")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

loginRepository.dart

```
class LoginRepository {
  static String urlLogin = API.url + '/authentication/api/login/';
  //static String urlLogin = API.url + '/authentication/api/login/ADMIN/12345';

  static Future<LoginResponse> login(Map<String, dynamic> loginPost) async {
    try {
      final response =
          await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(urlLogin), body: loginPost);
      print(response.statusCode);
      // if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body.toString());
      return LoginResponse.fromMap(json.decode(response.body));
      // } else {
      //   return null;
      // }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**(SERVER SITE)**

```
router.post('/api/login/:userNo/:password',(req,res)=>{
    var userNo = req.params.userNo;
    var password = req.params.password;

    let Status;
    
    const formData = {
        userNo: userNo,
        password : password
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting with `body` doesn't give you a URL path, example where **id = 1**:

1. Post with URL: `await http.post('user/' + id);`

> https://user/1

2. Post with Body: `await http.post('user/', body:{'id': id});`

> https://user?id=1

So you should specify which one are you using in the server-side before doing the request with flutter.

Comment: Thanks really appreciated your help sir.